# How to translate this snippet of pandas code to pyspark

Tags: pyspark, aggregate-functions

I have the following code snippet written in Pandas.

```
grouped = df.groupBy('episode_id')
get_entropy = lambda x: entropy(x.value_counts(), base=2)
ops = dict()
ops.update({f:('entropy',get_entropy) for f in categorical_features})
df = grouped.agg(ops)
```

How can I translate into equivalent code compliant with Pyspark?

I wasn't able to find a solution using the agg function provided by PySpark.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody has the answer, I publish my personal solution.

```
def compute_entropy(x):
    counter = collections.Counter(x)
    probs = [counter[item]/len(x) for item in sorted(counter.keys())]
    ent = 0.
    for i in probs:
        ent -= i * math.log(i, 2)
    return ent #entropy(probs,base=2)/1.0
compute_entropy_udf = F.udf(compute_entropy, T.DoubleType())
entropy_cols = [compute_entropy_udf(F.collect_list(x)).alias('entropy_' + x) for x in categorical_features]
df1 = df.groupBy('episode_id').agg(*entropy_cols)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).